# ServerSocket File Transmission Missing Bytes

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

## Issue

I have confirmed via a packet sniffer that all data coming from the client is being totally sent, and that the data being received by the server is complete as well, however there is a slight problem.

Here is a basic representation of relevant parts of the client thread within the server.

```
this.data_in = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
this.in = new InputStreamReader(this.data_in);
```

The server will read in authentication data using the BufferedReader, and once authentication is complete it will read data from the socket, like so. The variable 'fos' is a FileOutputStream that the DataInputStream data is being written to.

```
int read = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
while((read = data_in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
    bytes_received += read;
}
```

This all seems correct in concept, however, in practice the first 1450 bytes of the file read in are missing. I have tried using a new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream()) in case the position in the stream was weird but still no luck. Thanks for any help!

## Update 1

So I could use BufferedReader functionality I made a method to read in string lines as I was using them before. See below code.

```
int input;
boolean run = true;
while((input = in.read()) != -1 && run) {
    run = true;
    char[] chars = Character.toChars(input);
    for(char c : chars) {
        if(c == '\n') {
            run = false;
            break;
        } else if(c != '\r') {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
}
```

As great of a solution it seemed, there is still 1450 bytes of information missing. Maybe I'm going in the wrong direction here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like the `BufferedReader` is the problem - according to http://ulibgcj.sourceforge.net/javadoc/java/io/BufferedReader.html is has default buffer size of 8192... whatever this default buffer size is in your case, the `BufferedReader` will advance the `data_in` in steps of that default buffer size... so even if you don't consume them `data_in` is usually on a position beyond the last bytes you consumed during authentication.

Comment: Sounds like the most reasonable answer, I will check into it.

Comment: to make sure we are not chasing the wrong problem please try to dump directly the `sock.getInputStream()` to a file without any further processing and check the contents regarding the data structure you expect (authentication info + data).

Comment: I just tested what using my new print method on the InputStreamReader would do and it is printing the correct bytes for the beginning of the file, which are missing. While possible but not quite desirable, is there a way to get bytes from this stream (I know it returns characters but converting to bytes is not desirable) or correctly set up the DataInputStream so it will read at the correct position?

Comment: not sure - but I think we are missing relevant source code, anything that accesses `data_in` or `in` or even `sock`... any other source that does access any ?

Comment: Nope, the code accesses the stream via the code in the original question in Update 1, and once authentication is complete the client transmits "START number" where number is the filesize of the file in bytes. Immediately after the bytes for the file are sent via a `DataOutputStream`. Whenever `data_in` is accessed though it is too far down the stream, versus when I directly try to keep accessing `in` which is at the correct position.

Comment: what happens if you don't instantiate this.in - just use data_in for everything from beginning to end... does it contain all bytes or is something missing ?

Comment: It does contain all bytes, however my reasoning for using the reader so it was less painful than actually converting the bytes to characters. That might not be the case anymore though, eh? ;)

Comment: you could always use `String notes = new String(dataBytes, "UTF-8");` for the conversion (doesn't seem painful)... for more information see http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. What I ended up doing was extending the `DataOutputStream` class and read in each byte and cast it to a char, using the comparison function from above to process a line. Since the readLine() method for `DataOutputStream` is deprecated and final I made my own. I just read all information directly from that. I'll eventually go through and clean this up to accommodate for multiple character encodings, but this should work as a temporary band-aid fix.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be keeping two separate stream/readers that refer to the same thing: `this.data_in` and `this.in`. Reading from either will advance the stream, and then reads from the other will appear to "miss" the data that was read in the other. Also, you're using the [DataInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) just like a regular old InputStream by using the [read(byte[])](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29) method. DataInputStream is a specialized stream with a specific purpose.